# Is it possible to acces to the OS settigns with electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Is it possible to acces to the system settings of Windows / Mac Os / Linux with an electron app. Can the application edit the settings of the system, especially for windows. If it's possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Display a dialogue such as "Please increase your volume."

Comment: You have the full range of Node.js APIs and `npm` modules at your disposal in Electron apps, so yes, you can access and change settings. Depending on what you want to access or change there may or may not already be a module written to do it for you, but you have full access to the system, so...

Comment: Have you an exemple please? I'm pretty a newbie about node.js. Actually i try to acces to the proxy settings of the system. I saw it's pretty simple to open the proxy settings windows, but i actually want to edit the settings in the background, to be transparent for the user